Left-Align Section Title After Using Wraptable
I created a table that is placed next to some text:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Table Scaling Ansatz
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{wraptable}{l}{5.5cm}
    \caption{Scaling Ansatz}
    \label{sa}
    {\rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
    \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
    \Rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{tabular}{
    |P{2.4cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{2cm}|P{1.15cm}|P{1.8cm}|P{0.25cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{} \\
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \textbf{z} \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\text{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,x$ & $y_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,y$ & $T_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,x$ & $y_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,y$ & $T_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}}
    \centering
\end{wraptable}
\blindtext[3]
\newpage
\section{B}
\end{document}

The question:
How can I left-align \section{B}?

It works if you replace \newpage with \clearpage.

\begin{wraptable}[40]{l}{5.5cm} should do the trick. As an alternative, you may want to consider transposing the table in order to avoid the hassle with rotating the table and wrapping text around it.
